# Swift Passing Data in a tableview cell to a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parsing

I seem to be running into an issue and don't know where I am going wrong. I am trying to send the user's post to another view controller through a button, and my app keeps crashing. Below is the code for the tableview cell and the the prepare for segue. I am still new to the app development world. So I am sorry if my code is a little messy. Also I am using Parse as my backend. I don't know if that makes a difference.

thank you in advanced!

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimelineTableViewCell

        let userPost: PFObject = self.userObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        cell.reportPost.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.reportPost.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

//        Display Users Post's
        var userText = userPost["text"] as? String
        cell.TextLabel!.text = userText

//      Display Date and Time

        var Date: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        Date.dateFormat = "MM-dd HH:mm"
        cell.dateLabel.text = Date.stringFromDate(userPost.createdAt!)

//      Display username

        var findUser:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
        let Id = userPost.objectForKey("username")?.objectId as NSString!
        findUser.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: Id)
        findUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil{
                var user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray!).lastObject as! PFUser

                cell.userLabel.text = user.username

//              Getting User's Profile Image

                var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "PAHS_Logo")
                cell.userImage.image = initialThumbnail

                if let PhotoFile = user["ProfileImage"] as? PFFile {
                    PhotoFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
                        (ImageData:NSData?, error:NSError?)->Void in
                        if error == nil{
                            let Image:UIImage = UIImage(data: ImageData!)!
                            cell.userImage.image = Image
                        }else{
                            cell.userImage.image = initialThumbnail
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return cell
    }


    func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!){
        let titleString = self.userObjects.objectAtIndex(sender.tag) as? String
        let firstActivityItem = "\(titleString)"
        let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)
        self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    var valueToPass: String!

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;
        valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel?.text
        performSegueWithIdentifier("reportPost", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "reportPost")
        {
            var viewController: reportViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! reportViewController
            let indexPath = self.tableView!.indexPathsForSelectedRows();
            let titleString = userObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.count) as! String
            viewController.titleString = titleString
            viewController.titleLabel.text = valueToPass  //fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
            self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `performSegueWithIdentifier("reportPost", sender: self)` to `performSegueWithIdentifier("reportPost", sender: indexPath)` Then, in `prepareForSegue()`, the `sender` is going to be the indexPath. You can change your `prepareForSegue()` to this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   if (segue.identifier == "reportPost")
   {
        var viewController: reportViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! reportViewController
        let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath
        let titleString = userObjects[indexPath.row] as! String // I am assuming userObjects is the object containing the data you want
        viewController.titleString = titleString
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        let valueToPass = cell.textLabel?.text
        viewController.titleLabel.text = valueToPass
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

If you do it this way, you can get rid of `var valueToPass: String!` above `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

Comment: on the line "let titleString = userObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.count) as! String" it is saying "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value. I will keep playing around with it though.

Comment: @AllenSchuenke Is the titleString also coming from some element in the table view cell?

Comment: I am uploading it to dropbox and I will post the link for you, maybe it is my coding somewhere else. I am not sure to be honest

Comment: in the view controller that the info is being sent to, it has @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    var titleString = String()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.titleLabel.text = self.titleString
    }

Comment: here is the link to my project https://www.dropbox.com/s/dlk9p6hl1o0kin4/PAHS%20copy.zip?dl=0

Comment: @AllenSchuenke I updated my answer, including stuff in the first paragraph, so check it all. The only thing that may be weird is your `userObjects` object. I've assumed that you created that elsewhere in your class and it contains data that you need for the next view controller.

Comment: Awesome. It worked. Now onto my next part creating an email with the info on the new view controller

Comment: @AllenSchuenke Glad to hear it! Happy coding!